# How can I make a Cloudflare worker stream an OpenAI response back to the front-end?

Tags: service-worker, cloudflare, openai-api

I am trying to make a Cloudflare worker return chunks of data to the front-end instead of waiting for the full OpenAI result before responding. Currently, it does not seem to return any data before the full response is received from OpenAI.

Any idea of how to solve this (I am not that familiar with streaming data from the server to the front-end)?

**Worker code:** *I basically copied the following code from the [Cloudflare docs](https://developers.cloudflare.com/workers/examples/openai-sdk-streaming/) and made minor adjustments to the header configuration to avoid CORS errors during development.*

```
export default {
    async fetch(request, env, ctx) {
        const openai = new OpenAI({
            apiKey: "##-#######"
        })

        // make our request to the OpenAI API
        const stream = await openai.chat.completions.create({
            model: "gpt-3.5-turbo",
            messages: [{ role: "user", content: "Tell me a story using 2000 chars." }],
            stream: true
        },
            { responseType: "stream" }
        )

        // Using our readable and writable to handle streaming data
        let { readable, writable } = new TransformStream()

        let writer = writable.getWriter()
        const textEncoder = new TextEncoder()

        // loop over the data as it is streamed from OpenAI and write it using our writeable
        for await (const part of stream) {
            console.log(part.choices[0]?.delta?.content || "")
            writer.write(textEncoder.encode(part.choices[0]?.delta?.content || ""))
        }

        writer.close()

        const response = new Response(readable, {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'text/plain; charset=utf-8',
                'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
                'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept',
                'Transfer-Encoding': 'chunked'
            }
        });

        return response;
    }
}
```

**Front-end code:**

```
const onSubmit = async (data) => {
        try {
            // Fetch the streaming endpoint
            const response = await fetch('CLOUDFLARE_END_POINT');

            if (!response.body) {
                console.error('The browser does not support streaming responses or server did not send a stream.');
                return;
            }

            const reader = response.body.getReader();

            while (true) {
                const { done, value } = await reader.read();

                if (done) {
                    break;
                }

                // Convert each chunk to text and log/display it
                console.log(new TextDecoder().decode(value));
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error fetching the data:', error);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion:

```js
export default {
    async fetch(request: Request, env: Env, ctx: ExecutionContext): Promise<Response> {
        const openai = new OpenAI({
            apiKey: env.OPENAI_API_KEY,
            baseURL: env.CLOUDFLARE_OPEN_AI_GATEWAY,
        });

        const stream = await openai.chat.completions.create({
            model: 'gpt-3.5-turbo-0613',
            messages: [{ role: 'user', content: 'Write a story with 50 words.' }],
            max_tokens: 100,
            stream: true,
        });

        const readableStream = new ReadableStream({
            async start(controller) {
                for await (const part of stream) {
                    if (part.choices[0]?.delta?.content) {
                        const textEncoder = new TextEncoder();
                        const formattedData = `data: ${part.choices[0].delta.content}\n\n`;
                        controller.enqueue(textEncoder.encode(formattedData));
                    }
                }
                controller.close();
            },
        });

        return new Response(readableStream, {
            headers: {
                'content-type': 'text/event-stream',
                'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
                Connection: 'keep-alive',
                'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
                'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept',
            },
        });
    },
};
```